# portation: opencv 2.4.3 -> opencv 3.1., cvGetMat was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, opencv3.1

I am currently trying to port a code which is based on opencv 2.x to opencv 3.x (higher than 3.1). Within this code a function, namely cvGetMat(...) is being used. Since this function doesn't exist in opencv 3.x, I need a proper replacement. Does anyone know, how to replace this function properly? I already looked for it both in the opencv documentation and here at stackoverflow but couldn't find anything.

Here's a snipped code segment using this function

```
void cvCanny3(  const void* srcarr, void* dstarr,
            void* dxarr, void* dyarr,
            int aperture_size )
{


CvMat srcstub, *src = cvGetMat( srcarr, &srcstub );
CvMat dststub, *dst = cvGetMat( dstarr, &dststub );

CvMat dxstub, *dx = cvGetMat( dxarr, &dxstub );
CvMat dystub, *dy = cvGetMat( dyarr, &dystub );
...
...
...
}
```

When I run this code I just get following error as expected:

> ‘cvGetMat’ was not declared in this scope
>        CvMat srcstub, *src = cvGetMat( srcarr, &srcstub );
>                              ^~~~~~~~

Comment: can you please show what would be the exact conversion of `CvMat srcstub, *src = cvGetMat( srcarr, &srcstub );` in the new `cv::Mat` format? I'm still confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cvGetMat` is from old C-based interface (it creates a CvMat object from raw C array), you should convert your code to newer C++ interface and make it use `cv::Mat` type (wrap your `src_addr` C array to C++ `cv::Mat` instance).

E.g., your call to cvGetMat should be replaced by cv::Mat variable declaration.

```
cv::Mat src(num_rows, num_cols, src_type, src_arr);
```

The `num_rows`, `num_cols` and `src_type` determine size and semantics of `src_arr` array. Probably, you will have to drop 'const' modifier on you `src_arr` input.

See [`cv::Mat`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html) reference for more details.

All the `cvFunctionName` calls usually have their C++ counterparts in 'cv::' namespace. E.g., `cvRemap` would become `cv::remap` etc.